# JAXB Boolean Getter to Check for Existence of Node

Tags: java, jaxb, xmlbeans

I was trying to migrate a bulky piece of code from XMLBeans to JAXB. For the XMLBeans classes generated in the original code, there are a lot of isXXX() methods that are available to check for the existence of a XML tag. When I generated the JAXB classes no such methods were generated. I suspect there might be a way in JAXB to do it as well. I tried searching for a solution, but could not find an answer. I did redo a little bit of code migration by replacing the code with null checks instead. But it seems to be tedious. If there is a way to generate such methods, can you please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the

```
<jaxb:globalBindings generateIsSetMethod="true">
```

binding to generate `isSetXyz()` methods.

Comment: Danke! That was really helpful!